# DC to AC inverter shuts down unexpectedly

Tags: batteries, ac, dc, inverter

In my office I have setup a 400A 48V battery and an inverter that generates 220VAC. Inverter also charges the battery.

Here is the schema:
[image]

We recently brought a new 220AC line that comes from the main grid with 16mm2 aluminum cable and it is 500 meters long.

So the issue is, when the power from the main grid dies invertor also shutting down itself. I thought that we have more load on the inverter then expected and tried reproducing the issue by cutting the AC source to the inverter by turning odd the breaker and that doesn't reproduce the issue. I tried this many times and inverter works perfectly.

My question is why if the AC source on the main grid goes down  makes the inverter to shutdown?

**UPDATE:**

We figured that the inverter will shut down itself only incase if it's used closer to the limit(13A in this case). I am running the inverter for the last two weeks with load of less than 5A and it works fine. I guess it is a manufacturer issue.

Comment: Look up grid-tie inverter on the internets

Answer (score 2):

Your inverter works most probably in sync with your mains. Now when everything is ok the electronics in the inverter switch over to mains only. Eliminating losses on the output stage of the inverter. When the mains specs do no longer comply the controller detects this situation, the inverter takes over and continues to supply energy without a break.

When you cut the power it is clear for the controller that there is no power at all and the system takes over. However in case of a mains failure the power might not fail in the same way. This could lead to a situation that the controller can not order to take over and continue the supply.

It therefore looks a if the controller system in the inverter is not functioning the way it should. Verification of the system by an engineer from the manufacturer or agent is required.

To verify this situation more info is needed.

1. Find out if there is a dip in the office supply when the breaker is cut.

2.Can you start the inverter when there is no mains. (Stop the inverter, break the mains, Start the inverter).

There is no easy way to find a work around. It is all combined.

Comment: Is there anything that I could have before the inverter that will somehow kill the AC power to the inverter(as breaker kills it) so that my inverter keeps on working.

Comment: See my update and find out.

Comment: After the power goes off in the grid I can turn the inverter back on manually. I am not sure if I understand your first situation. What does dip mean?

Comment: The dip shows if the inverter needs time to kick in or that it takes over in an unnoticable manner.